# Is the regular represention of the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ indecomposable?

Tags: commutative-algebra, representation-theory, abelian-groups

If it is indecomposable, what are all the subrepresentations look like?

I feel that this problem is parallel to the problem of determining ideals of the Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1^{\pm1},x_2^{\pm1},\cdots,x_n^{\pm1}]$. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: It is the right direction. A decomposition $R = \mathbb C[x_1^{\pm 1}, ...] = A \oplus B$ makes $A$ a quotient ring of $R$. The projection $\pi : R \to R$ with image $A$ is idempotent and $\pi(1)$ is idempotent in $R$ (and the unit of $A$). So you only have to show, that $R$ has no nontrivial idempotents. You can show this by looking at degrees.

Comment: @JulianQuast Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just realized, that you don't even have to look at elements: If $e^2=e$ is idempotent, then $e(e-1) = 0$. If $R$ is an integral domain, then $e \in \{0,1\}$. But $R$ is an integral domain, since it is a localization of an integral domain (the polynomial ring).